What's the intuition behind $\frac{(a/b + b/a)}{2} \geq a + b -ab$?
I am helping a student in high school algebra. One of her problems was to show the above expression whenever $a,b > 0$. There is no clear restriction on what a and b is besides that. But suppose $a, b \in \mathbf{R}$. The hint she recieved was to move everything to the LHS of the inequality. Using that and multiplying through by $2ab$ we arrived at
$$a^2 + b^2 + 2(ab)^2 - 2a^{2}b - 2b^{2}a \geq 0 \tag{1}$$
From here we tried rewriting the expressions such that the LHS was a sum of terms all $\geq 0$. We tried using the fact that $(x + y)^2 \geq 0$ and then choosing appropriate x and y to rewrite (1).
Any ideas on if this is a good approach or any other results that could be useful?

Please check the tag descriptions before using the tags. This question has nothing to do with abstract algebra. Hence I have removed the tag.

Your approach is good. You won't be able to directly write the LHS as a square since it has five terms. Instead, we can split the $2a^2b^2$ term so that we can write this as two squares:
\begin{align*}a^2+b^2+2a^2b^2-2a^2b-2b^2a&=(a^2-2a^2b+a^2b^2)+(b^2-2b^2a+a^2b^2)\\
&=(a-ab)^2+(b-ab)^2\\
&\geq 0\end{align*}

Very nice! One observation from this - the LHS is zero at $a=b=0$ and at $a=b=1$ only. So the inequality actually holds for all of $(a,b)\in\mathbb{R}^2\setminus{(0,0)}$ and is strict for $(a,b)\in\mathbb{R}^2\setminus{(0,0),(1,1)}$.

@ChrisLewis Almost -- the inequality doesn't hold when exactly one of $a,b$ is negative, since there was multiplication by $2ab\geq0$ in the original post.

Well, and the original inequality cannot have either of $a, b$ to be zero, so best to have $ab>0$.

Thats it!!! We were trying things like $(x^2 + y)^2$ but kept running into pesky fourth degree terms.

@MaxChien good spot!

Despite holding for all positive reals, the inequality is not homogeneous. That means you can try simplifying it by multiplying all numbers in it by a common constant, $x$, and seeing if you get a simpler inequality for some  particular value of $x$. You'll notice that the LHS stays the same but the RHS is a parabola in $x$. The maximum of that parabola is
$$
1/4 (a/b + b/a) + 1/2
$$
so you are done if you can show that this is less than the LHS, which is equivalent to
$$
a/b + b/a \geq 2. 
$$
This, you already know how to do; multiplying both sides by $ab$ shows this is equivalent to  $(a-b)^2\geq 0$.

Some heuristic approach to "uncover" the factorization may be as follows. First, there is no immediate idea to factor either side of the inequality. Since it is symmetric, a natural first attempt would be to see what happens when they are equal - $a=b=x:$
$$LHS:=1\geq 2x-x^2:=RHS\iff 0\geq = -1+2x-x^2=-(1-x)^2.$$
So it looks like when you subtract $1$ from both sides, it might help:
$$LHS-1=\dfrac{1}{2}\left(\frac ab + \frac ba\right)-1 = \dfrac{(a-b)^2}{2ab}$$
and
$$ RHS-1=-1+a+b-ab = -(1-a)+b(1-a)=-(1-a)(1-b).$$
Then you bring the RHS over to the left, give common denominator and need to prove (ignoring the case $ab=0$):
$$(a-b)^2 + 2ab(1-a)(1-b)\geq 0.$$
At this point, one may well be stuck and that's fine. But if one does not give up and tries many different subsitutions etc, then the idea of $x=b(1-a)$ and $y = a(1-b)$ and $x-y=b-a$, which kills the problem is well within the reach. In fact, this is probably one of the top 3 things I would attempt.
Experienced solvers know how to solve an 8th grade problem like this and usually just immediately gives the shortest solution, as is done in textbooks, and so students themselves get in the habit of never really doing any "scratch work" or some playing around with terms. At least, I used to be like this when I was just learning algebraic expressions like this and my current proficiency is solely attributed to all the failures I used to get.
